# Oracle Java SE 8 release updates after January 2019

Tags: licensing

Our suite of applications heavily depend on Java. One of our customers came across this link https://www.java.com/en/download/release_notice.jsp and are asking us to explain what it really means? Does this mean our customers would need a license to use Java 8 or it's new features after January 2019?

> ## Oracle Java SE 8 Release Updates
>
> Public updates for Oracle Java SE 8 will remain available for individual, personal use through at least the end of 2020.
>
> Public updates for Oracle Java SE 8 released after January 2019 will not be available for business, commercial or production use without a commercial license.
>
> If you are a CONSUMER using Java for individual, personal use, you will continue to have the same access to Oracle Java SE 8 updates as you do today through at least the end of 2020. In most instances, the Java-based applications you run are licensed separately by a company other than Oracle (for example, games you play on your PC are likely developed by a gaming company). These applications may run on the Java platform and be dependent on Oracle Java SE 8 updates beyond 2020. Accordingly, Oracle recommends you contact your application provider for details on how they plan to continue to provide application support to you.
>
> If you are a DEVELOPER, Oracle recommends you review the roadmap information for Java SE 8 and beyond and take appropriate action depending on the type of application you develop and your distribution model.
>
> If you are acting on behalf of an ENTERPRISE, Oracle recommends you review the roadmap information for Java SE 8 and beyond and begin to assess your ongoing Java support requirements in order to migrate to a later release or obtain a commercial license, as appropriate, on a timely basis.
>
> If you are an ORACLE CUSTOMER who is licensed to use Java SE as part of another Oracle product, you continue to have access to Oracle Java SE 8 updates beyond 2019 for use with those Oracle products, see this My Oracle Support (MOS) note for more information.

Comment: Note that, apart from Oracle Java SE, there is also [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK), which is free software and almost 100% compatible. That's what most Java users migrate to.

Comment: @sleske Yes, thanks and that's what we eventually moved to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it means you need to licence it under the DEVELOPER roadmap.